# How to filter user pasted content in contenteditable div?

Tags: dart

I have a div which allow contenteditable.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

I would like to filter all html tags copy & pasted from user (except ), how this could achieve in Dart code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myDiv.onPaste.listen((e) {
  // do filtering here and then insert the result imperatively
  // one or both of the following might be necessary to prevent
  // the default paste behavior happening as well.
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

See also:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933677/217408
- [Detect a paste event in a contenteditable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190770)